# Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf is not working

Tags: java, arrays, search, java-8

Consider the following snippet

```
 int key1 = Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}).indexOf(5) ;//wrapper 
 int key2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5})).indexOf(5); //another copy
```

But this snippet evaluates to -1 -1 which means It did not find the key 5 in the list.
But why `Arrays.aslist` not finding the key in list. Can anyone please explain or quick fix to code for Searching key in array without explicit logic implementation. Of course we can sort it then use `Arrays.binarySearch`. Any other suggestions or any other ways to do this.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5).indexOf(5) ;`

Comment: Or `int key1 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5}).indexOf(5) ;`

Comment: I prefer the first one, as it is more intuitive and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the type of Array you're creating inside the `asList()`, Considering that the List types require non-primitive types, you need to declare `int` as `Integer`. If you change your code to:

`Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5}).indexOf(5);`

It will work.

Comment: I find `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5)` to be more intuitive and readable.